# Script doesn't autoclick anymore properly

Tags: vb.net, authentication, browser

I have a script that logs into a website and can autoclick something very fast for the given interval. Now ever since I added my newest detail in, everything in the script works, except the autoclicker. Once I click the button to start the autoclicker it doesn't even click once. 
Here is the code I just added

```
 With WebBrowser1

        Do Until Not (.IsBusy)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop

        Do Until .ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop


    End With

    Dim htmlText As String

    If Not (WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml) Is Nothing Then

        htmlText = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml

        If InStr(htmlText, "Microsoft account") Then

            MessageBox.Show("You have entered in a wrong password or the account doesn't exist.")
            'code to go here if it is true
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Sign in successful. Proceed on...")
            'code to go here if it is false




        End If

    End If
```

what the code does is it tells you if you used the correct login credentials or the wrong ones. But i don't understand how that would affect my autoclicking button?

```
     Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 40
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 100
    Else
        Timer1.Interval = 500
    End If

    Timer1.Start()



    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub
```

Where timer1 =

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub
```

Comment: Check whether function `Timer1_Tick` is being called, e.g. put `MessageBox.Show` inside this function.

Comment: Yes, I put the message box in the timer1, then clicked the button and it spammed me with a bunch of messages lol. I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working though...

Comment: Does element with id `claimIt` still on the page? Does it have member `Click`? Is this member really a function? Please, check these things in `Button1_Click_1` function.

Comment: The function fully works when the code isn't there. All these are necessary for it to work I believe, because without them it wouldn't work. Maybe my source can help you out ? http://pastebin.com/V5c7z9Y9 Idk i've been stuck with this problem for a while now..

Comment: Looks like you don't really have element with id `claimIt` on your page. Create a chain of variables to find the source of `NullPointerException`: `Dim varWebBrowser = WebBrowser1`, then `Dim varDocument = varWebBrowser.Document`, then `Dim varButton = varDocument.GetElementById("claimIt")` and, finally, `varButton.InvokeMember("Click")`

Comment: I thought that would work for sure... It did bring a debug document up if that helps, and it listed all of this: http://pastebin.com/Ta1zbg5R but the code itself seemed like it would work, but didn't :\ no matter how much I click onthe button, it doesn't even click once.

Comment: Look at the screenshot you posted earlier: http://gyazo.com/a6499727fb3f8840e5e5a2890872757a The problem is that you have `NullPointerException` because something does not exist at the moment when you call the function. Please, do what I said in my previous comment and let us know where the exception will occur (post a screenshot).

Comment: Here is what I get when I do this: http://gyazo.com/28547143fe48f6b5f8e957f9a0126a64 No matter where I put your code (in the timer or on the autoclick button function) I always get that type of message. I have no idea how this happened or what your script did to change it, but still.

Comment: Since I don't know Visual Basic, I might have made a mistake with variable definition. You write on Visual Basic, so remove that code and declare variables yourself. Declare variable with name `varDocument` and set it value to `WebBrowser1.Document`, then declare variable with name `varButton` and set it value to `varDocument.GetElementById("claimIt")`. Finally, call `varButton`'s method `Click`. Post the screenshot with error.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't you already tell me that code?  http://pastebin.com/wy0UfPD2 but the error is strange, as you can see it does not present me with an error at first. Here's what happens (http://gyazo.com/878f66eb1e2b43ca4ba41795be1c0a1e) I type in the Gamertag, and press Turbo. When I press Turbo the tag is entered in but nothing is claimed. So as soon as I close out it takes me to debug mode and tells me this (http://gyazo.com/90a6ab323d30ae29b7f36d32e216c42d) I hit yes and it brings me this (http://pastebin.com/ywvY15LG)

Comment: Okay, let's revert to original code. Do you still have `NullPointerException` as you said earlier: http://gyazo.com/a6499727fb3f8840e5e5a2890872757a ?

Comment: Very strange. I went back to what I had and I can't have that error. I believe it is because the "click" command is right, it works without the code I have above (in my first post, 1st code), but as soon as I put in that 1st code, the code works relatively good, but the autoclicker stops working (I have no idea what else to say other than that)

Comment: Check (via adding the message box) if timer tick function is still being called. If it is, then write three lines: in first line declare variable and set it value to WebBrowser1.Document, in second line declare variable and set it value to `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt")`. In third line write `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")`. Now put your message box between first and second lines, check whether it works, if it does, then put it between second and third. If it still works, put it after third line. If you get error, post a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `timer1.enable = true`, else it wont be work.

Comment: When I do that I still get errors, no matter where I put  that http://gyazo.com/a6499727fb3f8840e5e5a2890872757a edit: Source: http://pastebin.com/V5c7z9Y9

Comment: What mean by click? it looks like not attach to your button

Comment: It's attached to a timer that runs through the button (autoclicker - does the clicking for me)